# Attribute Key Not Found Error SSAS Cube Rebuild

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, dimension, ssas-2008

I am rebuilding my SSAS cube and encountering the following error

```
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when 
processing: Table: 'MyFactTable', Column: 'MyKey', Value: 
'900763'. The attribute is 'Description'. Errors in the OLAP storage 
engine: The attribute key was converted to an unknown member because the 
attribute key was not found. Attribute Description of Dimension: Item
from Database: OTD DATAMART, Cube: Data Mart, Measure Group: Transaction 
Fact, 
Partition: Transaction Fact, Record: 22438443.
```

I realize this could be the key was in my fact table but not in dimension so I process update the dimension first and the process the cube, but this error keeps bumping up. I can confirm that I can see the key and the entry in the dimension.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your fact table('MyFactTable') column('MyKey') is having value '900763', which is not present in the related Dimension table. Check the dimension table for value '900763'. If it's not there, Insert it.

Comment: But it is there

Comment: Process the Dimension as Process Full, and then process the cube.

Comment: I did but no good.

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the dimension from the cube, then adding back into the cube -  effectively resetting the Dimension Usage.  Or maybe try changing the key of the dimension to be a different field and then change back again.  Basically anything to try and jog things back into resetting the keys in the background.  Then reprocess the database in full (if you can, otherwise process the dimension and then the cube).

Answer (score 1):

After adding the dimension to the cube, on the dimension usage table remove all the dimension key references to the measure groups and try processing the cube. Then add them back in. It is some disconnect on the keys because the fact attribute all check out. Sometimes removing the dimension from the cube and then reprocessing the cube before deleting the dimension on the server side prior to re-adding works.